# Windows authentication prior to posting data, what am I missing?

Tags: android

I have an android app that is working fine when connected to a production web server.  A development server was created for testing future releases. It's an IIS server that's locked down with username/password.

I am trying to use httpclient.getCredentialsProvider() to send a username and password so I can authenticate to the page before doing anything else but it doesn't seem to be working correctly so I assume I am missing some code or doing something wrong.

I tried messing with the credentials and sending the port and full url but that didn't work either so I just switched it to null and -1 which from what I gather means it should work on any site any port, but every way I tried still got the same result of not authenticating.

Here is what I have now.

```
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null,-1), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("someusername", "somepassword")); 
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("someURL");
```

Other non-relevant code to set Name Value Pair for posting

Then

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
httpost.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

Answer (score 0):

> IIS supports HTTP authentication methods like Basic, Digest and Integrated. The problem is that all of them are hardwired to Windows accounts. This means that you need a Windows user on your server for every account you want to HTTP-auth enable.
>   Having the ability to do plain Basic Authentication agains account stored e.g. in a database would be very handy for a range of situations like web applications, (WCF) web services, REST services, Silverlight service backends etc.

[enter link description here](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1669)